# Is here a potential ConcurrentModificationException? and is my solution right?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am on a project in which there is a class like below.

```
class Container{
  List<Container> dependencies;
  //... other members and methods.
  addDependent(Container con){
    for(Container c : dependencies){
      if(c.id == con.id) return;
      dependencies.add(c);
    }
  }
}
```

and we compute a list of containers like below. Be mindful that the list is huge and the computation for each iteration is complex (I just keep the relevance here)

```
List<Container> list = // initialized;
for (container c : list){
  c.addDependent(c);
  //other computation to populate container's other properties.
}
```

This code snippet is in a single thread and it works fine, only that it's slow - bcoz of the size of the list. Now I try improving the performance by breaking the list into four sublists and run the same code in four threads and put them together again after they're done (the synchronizer `CountdownLatch` is employed).

Now I got `ConcurrentModificationException` error. After some hair-pulling I use a ThreadLocal variable to wrap up "List dependencies" in the first code snippet and the CME is gone.

however the problem is I am not quite sure why the exception occurred in the first place and if my solution is a proper one, or it will explode again at some point in the future.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a `List` and not a `Set`?

Comment: You are modifying the same collection you are iterating. This leads to CME, it does not even have to do with multithreading.

Comment: If you are using this list in a synchronized environment, you cannot use `ArrayList`.  You must do one of the following: 1) use `Collections.synchronizedList()` method, or 2) use its thread-safe variant: `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. As @EdwinDalorzo pointed out, READ THE DOCUMENTATION before using `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

### About Concurrent Modification Exception

This exception is not necessarily thrown in a multithreaded code. It happens when you modify a collection while it is being iterated. You can get this exception even in single-threaded applications. For instance, in a for-each loop, if you remove or add elements to a list, you end up getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

As such, adding synchronization to the code will not necessarily solve the problem. Some alternatives consist in making a copy of the data to be iterated, or using iterators that accept modifications (i.e. ListIterator), or a collection with snapshot iterators.

Evidently, in a multithreaded piece of code, you would still have to take care of synchronization to avoid further problems.

In your code above you have exactly that problem. You wrote:

`for(Container c : dependencies){
      if(c.id == con.id) return;
      dependencies.add(c);
    }`

Which is potentially modifying the same collection under iteration in the for-each loop and you can potentially get a CME every time you do not satisfy the condition evaluated in the if statement.

Let me give some examples:

Let's say you want to delete items from a collection while iterating over it. Your alternatives to avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException` are:

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
books.add(new Book(new ISBN("0-201-63361-2")));
books.add(new Book(new ISBN("0-201-63361-3")));
books.add(new Book(new ISBN("0-201-63361-4")));
```

Collect all the records that you want to delete within an enhanced for loop, and after you finish iterating, you remove all found records.

```
ISBN isbn = new ISBN("0-201-63361-2");
List<Book> found = new ArrayList<Book>();
for(Book book : books){
    if(book.getIsbn().equals(isbn)){
        found.add(book);
    }
}
books.removeAll(found);
```

Or you may use a `ListIterator` which has support for a remove/add method during the iteration itself.

```
ListIterator<Book> iter = books.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().getIsbn().equals(isbn)){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

In a multithreaded environment, you might consider making a copy of the collection before iterating, as such, allowing others to modify the original collection without affecting iteration:

```
synchronized(this.books) {
   List<Book> copyOfBooks = new ArrayList<Book>(this.books)
}
for(Book book : copyOfBooks) {
   System.out.println(book);
}
```

Alternatively, you may consider using other types of collections using snapshot iterators, like `java.util.ConcurrentCopyOnWriteArrayList` which guarantees not to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. But read the documentation first, because this type of collection is not suitable for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying any collection you are iterating (except if you modify through the Iterator) will lead to a `ConcurrentModificationException`. However, after looking at your class, I'd like to propose an alternate solution.

Right now you are storing all of your objects in a `List` and testing each one to see if they are a member. If you switch this structure to a `Set`, which enforces only one of each type of object, it might make your code clearer.

```
class Container{
    Set<Container> dependencies = new HashSet<>();

    public void addDependent(Container con) {
       dependencies.add(c);
    }

    public boolean equals(Container c) {
       return c.id = this.id;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
       // etc
    }
}
```

Notice that you will have to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` on your `Container` object in order for the `Set` to be able to tell the `Containers` apart.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Todd that moving to a Set will be more efficient, especially since the poster indicated that dependencies gets large.  However, unless you can come up with a nicely distributed set of hashCode values, it may be more efficient to use a TreeSet.  If you do, you'll need to correctly implement the Comparable interface (read it carefully).

Even though we've moved away from the original implementation, I'd like to point out that

```
addDependent(Container con){
  for(Container c : dependencies){
    if(c.id == con.id) return;
    dependencies.add(c);
  }
}
```

adds c to dependencies for every item it doesn't match.  For example, if the existing ids in Containers within dependencies were (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), and you called addDependent with a Container having id of 6, you'd end up with (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6).  Furthermore, with this bug, you'd never add anything to dependencies, because you only add if the list is non-empty already.  You should have moved the add outside the for loop:

```
addDependent(Container con){
  for(Container c : dependencies){
    if(c.id == con.id) return;
  }
  dependencies.add(c);
}
```

This would have worked correctly and eliminated the CME, though for large dependencies lists, the Set approach will perform better.